# MYSQL codes not being read

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4, mariadb-10.3

When I input a code or anything into MySQL and hit "enter" it moves down and "->" appears. It is as if the code is not going through or the code is not being read.

I have attempted to download "add-ons" but I am really not sure what I am doing. This is for school and I am having trouble getting in touch with the professor.

I am new to this and can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help!

Please see image of what it looks like to me.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do? Just try help on the client prompt?  type help;  without quotes. Type quit to quit .  Ignore the single quotes in the "welcome message"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add semicolon ; after the mysql code.

Comment: Did this really help?

Comment: I doubt that :)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1:** Be aware of the prompt.  Either of these

```
MariaDB >
mysql >
```

means that you are inside the MySQL commandline tool.  You can enter only SQL statements.  Most SQL queries need to be terminated by a `;` or `\G` (but not both).  To exit that tool:

```
exit
```

Or, if you get stuck in certain ways

```
CTRL-C
exit
```

Each of these implies a shell script:

```
$
#
mymachine$
/usr/home/rj $
C:\Users\rj:
```

and many others

**Problem 2:** `mysqldump` is a command, not SQL.  So it needs to be executed in a shell script.

**Problem 3:** There is yet another problem.  When it suggested typing `'help;'`, it did not mean for you to include the quotes.  Instead, type just `help;`.